# Modifying Outlook 2010 autocomplete stream

Tags: c#, outlook

I am accesssing the Outlook 2010 cache using the below code and modifying it.

Please let me know how i can udpate the entry back to inbox mail store.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

StorageItem storage = inboxFolder.GetStorage("IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete", OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByMessageClass);

PropertyAccessor propertyAcc = storage.PropertyAccessor;

byte[] got = propertyAcc.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C090102");
```

Thanks
Jaspreet Singh

Answer (score 1):

Are you parsing the autocomplete cache blob? Is using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) an option (I am its author)? It exposes autocomplete as the [RDONicknames](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdonicknames.htm) collection:

```
 set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
 Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
 set Nicknames = Session.GetNicknames
 set NickName = Nicknames.Add("Joe The User <test@dimastr.com>")
 Nicknames.Save
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Thanks for your reply. i have already use Set property like below                                                                   List<byte> lstGot;
            lstGot=GetList(got);
             
 propertyAcc.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C090102", lstGot.ToArray());                                                                  But it's not saving bytes to mail store. Do i need to do something else to save updated Stream to mail Store.                                                              Thanks Jaspreet Singh

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Can you please suggest any way to delete autocomplete entries from cache. For example I would like to delete all entries having domain @gmail.com. And updated stream should got stored in mail store. That way i want to have control of autocomplete entries in cache as per need. Thanks Jaspreet Singh

Comment: You would need to parse the nicknames blob and update it appropriately. While it is definitely doable, the blob is as binary as it gets. Is using Redemption an option? It parses the blob for you.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for your reply. What i am doing is. Converting bytes i got from above to  List<byte> lstGot = got.OfType<byte>().ToList(); and getting number of rows by using below                                                            int numberRows = ByteArrToInt(got.Skip<byte>(12).Take<byte>(4).ToArray<byte>());                                                                 Then i am calculating Start Position and end position of that row and deleting that row. But once i delete it and save it. My autocomplete got corrupt. Thanks Jaspreet Singh

Comment: Please let me know what does it mean by "Parse the nicknames blob". Can you please give some example.   Thanks Jaspreet Singh